# How to have CSS :target match a second click?

Tags: css

I have a small html like this:

```css
h1:target {
  animation: yellow-fading 0.8s linear;
}

@keyframes yellow-fading {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#title1">[Flash-title1]</a> <a href="#title2">[Flash-title2]</a>

<h1 id="title1">Title 1</h1>
<h1 id="title2">Title 2</h1>
```

My purpose is to do a background color flashing for the target I just clicked. It works(on Chrome 75), but with a flaw.

If I click [Flash-title1] twice in succession, the second click will **not** match the `h1:target` rule so the color flashing does not occur. How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You can't. The animation fires when the selector becomes valid. Since `:target` isn't changing, the selector doesn't become valid again. Use JavaScript instead.

Comment: With javascript

Comment: Then is there a JavaScript way to clear the `:target` cache?

Comment: there is no cache. `:target` triggers when `yoursite.com/#ThisIsATarget` is active. You have to remove `#ThisIsATarget` from your url, then the css will run again if you click again.